# flutter_webview_plugin keeps laoding

Tags: linux, google-chrome, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

So I am planning to make a webapp using flutter where it will display another website like duckduckgo.com when I tried to use flutter_webview_plugin the wepapp keeps loading and never displays the website I am trying to integrate in my webapp. By the way, I am using the same exact code from flutter's website. Note, I updated pubspec.yaml file then I installed the package using this command `flutter pub get` here is the source code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
          url: "https://www.duckduckgo.com",
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Widget webview"),
          ),
        ),
      },
    );
 }
}
```

By the way I am using a Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

add new key to ios/Runner/Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```